# Firestore security rules - how to secure LIST requests by request.query checks on ACL access control list?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to secure a collection of `accounts` documents with a field `access.users` that contains an array of user `DocumentReference`s which are allowed to access an account document in the collection.

```
accounts.access.users = [ //array of user document references ]
```

In my query (JS client library) I am setting the query:

```
db.collection('accounts').where('access.users', 'array-contains', userRef)
```

To secure the data, I want to write a rule:

```
 function userHasAccountAccess () {
   let user = getUser(); // returns users document reference based on auth uid
   // - here - need to check that the users document reference was requested by the query ie - that `request.query` contains the `access.users` field and that value of this filter in an array/list which includes a reference to the users' document
 }

 match /accounts/{docId} {
  list: if userHasAccountAccess();
 }
```

... but it seems from the docs that the only properties available on a query are `limit`, `offset` and `orderBy`, so then I am unable to test or secure this way.

So how are others securing their data in this type of access role ACL scenario for `LIST` type requests?

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging, I found the answer.

Where posting a query (LIST) request as so:

```
db.collection('accounts').where('access.users', 'array-contains', userRef).limit(5)
```

... it seems that `limit`, `orderBy` and `offset` become properties of `request.query` in the security rules, but the `where` filters become properties of `resource.data`.

This is confusing because a) resource.data is usually a map of document data being posted (ie when saving records) and b) [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data) describe `resource.data` as such.